# How to insert java Char to MariaDB CHAR(1) through spring boot batch JdbcBatchItemWriter()

Tags: java, mariadb, spring-batch

I have a table with column data type as CHAR(1). Now I need to insert java Char value to this column. This is how the table is created

```
CREATE TABLE db1.test_table (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  last_updated DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2;
```

A char in Java is a UTF-16 code unit so that can be the issue but how do we work around. I am using this in Spring Boot batch application where I am reading from and writing into databases. Apparantly reader is setting database CHAR(1) value into Java Char but the JdbcBatchItemWriter is throwing error as below

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'user_status' at row 1
```

Here is my ItemWriter()

```
        @Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> loadUserWriter() {
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo>();
            writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
            writer.setSql("INSERT INTO db1.test_table "
                    + "(user_id, user_status, last_updated)" 
                    + "VALUES (:userId, :userStatus, NOW())");
            writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return writer;
        }
```

Here is my Model class

```
            public class UserInfo {
                private int userId;
                private char userStatus;
                
                public int getUserId() {
                    return userId;
                }
                public void setUserId(int userId) {
                    this.userId = userId;
                }
                public char getUserStatus() {
                    return userStatus;
                }
                public void setUserStatus(char userStatus) {
                    this.userStatus = userStatus;
                }
                    
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver is mapping the `CHAR(1)` to/from a `String`, even though the length is fixed at 1.

I believe the error is because the JDBC driver treats the `char` value as a number, and converts the number to a `String`. That string has multiple digits, so it is too long for the `CHAR(1)` column.

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: @Thomson Give the value to JDBC as a `String`. Either change method `char getUserStatus()` to `String getUserStatus()`, or don't use `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` so you can convert the type when mapping the values.

Comment: I changed the method from char to String and it worked. Never thought that will work. Thank you very much!